# How to choose the frequency value without knowing the seasonality of the data in R ts() package

Tags: r, time-series, seasonality, trend, frequency

I am trying to analyze the S$P 500 data on Kaggle.
I have a daily values of the opening stock prices.

As frequency is the number of observations taken in a cycle, I am guessing I need to know the seasonality of the data before deciding upon the frequency value.

I have read that I can use msts and give multiple frequencies as inputs. Will R check which among the multiple frequencies is the best and then estimate the seasonality and trend?

And also can someone tell me what happens when I set frequency='periodic' in ts() function?

Comment: What seasonal cycles do you expect to see in the US stock market?  (If you haven't any idea, then consider analyzing some other kind of data instead.)

Comment: How do tell whether there is seasonality in the data.What should I look at to confirm the absence of seasonality or trend?

Comment: For one approach, search our site for [SARIMA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=sarima).  You can also search generally for [seasonal decomposition](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=season*+decomp*).

Answer (score 1):

If you are examining data that you believe contains one or more periodic signals, with unknown frequency, a natural thing to do is to plot the intensity of the data in the frequency domain (via a Fourier transform).  This can be implemented in `R` using the `intensity` function in the [`ts.extend` package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ts.extend/versions/0.1.1) (see also [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.12416) explaining the package).  When you plot the intensity of the signal in the frequency domain you will see "spikes" at the frequencies where there are periodic signals.  You can also test whether these spikes are sufficiently large to distinguish from noise using the [`spectrum.test` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ts.extend/versions/0.1.1/topics/spectrum.test).

Answer (score 0):

You can safely assume 5 to begin with ( make sure you have NO MISSING DAYS i.e. fill in a local average for any day that there are no observed values. Good software can detect other cycles if they are present for example a monday effect or the first week-of-the-month effect et al .

Make sure you detect anomalies and suitably adjust the data for their effect otherwise memory effects will/can be occluded.

In response to your question .. 1) adjust for anomalies  ... 2 ) use 4 daily dummy indicators ....3) examine the residuals for persistent effects suggesting a cycle greater than 5 via the acf and/or intervention detection schemes in a trial and error manner.

Comment: Hi.Can you tell me how to generally select the value for frequency.What should I be looking at?

Comment: And also can you tell me what happens when I set frequency='periodic' in ts() function.Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea as to what happens as I have no familiarity with anything that would use  a periodicity of 365.25 as we generally do not do on day x of the year what we did last year on day x EXCEPT for major holidays.